# Using 2 equal fields in 2 different databases databases PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm gonna try to explain this as well as I possibly can. I'm creating a translation function and it is based on every text having a code value. For an example: a title for a certain page has a code and a value associated with the code.

I have 2 tables: translations: where all the codes and values are kept and a table where there is just the code itself and it goes through a function that takes it through the translation table:

```
public function T($code) {
      $value = $code;
      $db_value = $this->db->getRow("SELECT value FROM translations WHERE code = '".$code."'");
      if($db_value) {
        $value = $db_value['value'];
      }
            return $value;
        }
```

GetRow is a custom function that select a single column from a table:

```
function getRow() {
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args == 0) {
        return null;
    } else if ($func_num_args == 1) {
        $this->query($func_get_args[0]);
    } else {
        $args = array();
        $query = $func_get_args[0];
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        foreach ($func_get_args as $arg) {
            if (is_string($arg) && !is_numeric($arg)) {
                $args[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $arg);
            } else {
                $args[] = $arg;
            }
        }
        $this->query(vsprintf($query, $args));
    }
    return ($this->rows() ? $this->fetch() : null);
}
```

Now making the admin page for the site I ran into a problem, I want the code of the texts to be hidden and display the text that the code represents. My current elect looks a little likee this: it doesnt work however, it only selects the columns but doesnt find any rows:

```
  SELECT vc.*,
       t.code,
       t.value
  FROM vakances_card AS vc 
  JOIN translations AS t 
  ON vc.title = t.code 
  AND vc.descr = t.code
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. You may change your query to

```
SELECT vc.*,
   t.code,
   t.value
FROM vakances_card AS vc 
JOIN translations AS t 
ON vc.title = t.code 
AND vc.descr = t.code
```

To the following query

```
SELECT vc.*,
   t.code,
   t.value
FROM vakances_card AS vc 
LEFT JOIN translations AS t 
ON vc.title = t.code 
AND vc.descr = t.code
```

Or may change to

```
SELECT vc.*,
   t.code,
   t.value
FROM vakances_card AS vc 
RIGHT JOIN translations AS t 
ON vc.title = t.code 
AND vc.descr = t.code
```

Comment: When I did both of those selects in MySQL Workbench, when it was LEFT JOIN all the translations were null, and when it was RIGHT JOIN all the cards side was null when i did INNER JOIN it didn't find aything

Comment: Then problem is with following line

ON vc.title = t.code 
AND vc.descr = t.code

do you have anything which match in both tables?

like join vc.code = t.code

Then it'll work fine for you.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/c8ae6ec0cb16d630617e47e18ea8dbe1.png this is what i get in workbench, the code is equal to title and descr

Comment: oh you are matching strings. change = sign with like statement. E.g

t.code like CONCAT('%', vc.title,'%')

Comment: I'm still having the issue of the join, cause one side is always null and none of the join types worked for me

Comment: Can you share your database table record so that we can have clear picture?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/250df43a3d3318ff0f38840e01836e53.png - Translations Table https://i.gyazo.com/025ba8d5680eb187b2075e97bde5cbcd.png - Vakances_card table

Comment: `SELECT vc.*, t.code, t.value FROM vakances_card vc, translations t WHERE vc.title = t.code` this works only partially i need the description to be there as well but i cant figure out how to have both title and description to match

Comment: As i can see in database table. None of the entries are matching in both vc.title & t.code. That is why you are not getting anything. vc.title value should be same as t.code or vice versa. Then you'll get all.

Comment: the translations table is quite massive and it has way more records than shown, although i did figure out the correct select that worked for me `SELECT vc.*,
                (SELECT value FROM translations WHERE code = vc.title) AS title_full,
                (SELECT value FROM translations WHERE code = vc.descr) AS descr_full
              FROM vakances_card vc` Thank you for all your help I really apreciate it!